# I cannot open my emulator on Android Studio, it says 'Not applicable for main.dart configuration'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

My device section shows 'AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile)' and I cannot connect my emulator to Android Studio. It also shows the section that shows my device is not applicable in main.dart in grey. I have no issues on flutter doctor. Can you please help me to figure out this problem? [image]

Comment: make sure your device is enabled the debugging mode.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled to debugging mode.